# Convert Audio data in IeeeFloat buffer to PCM in buffer

Tags: c#, naudio, pcm, wasapi

I use NAudio to capture sound input and the input appears as a buffer containing the sound information in IeeeFloat format.

Now that I have this data in the buffer, I want to translate it to PCM at a different sampling rate.

I have already figured out how to convert from IeeeFloat to PCM, and also convert between mono and stereo. Converting the sampling rate is the tough one.

Any solution, preferable using NAudio, that can convert the IeeeFLoat buffer to a buffer with PCM format of choice (including changing sampling rate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resample while you receive data, then you need to perform input driven resampling. I wrote [an article on this](http://markheath.net/post/input-driven-resampling-with-naudio-using-acm) a while ago.

NAudio has some helper classes to go from mono to stereo, and float to PCM, but they tend to operate on `IWaveProvider` or `ISampleProvider` inputs. Typically if I just had the samples as a raw block of bytes I'd write by own simple code to go from float to PCM and double up the samples. It's not that hard to do and the `WaveBuffer` class will allow you to read float samples directly from a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. In the article you linked you say that the ACMStream does not need floating point samples. Does it mean that it wont work on floating point samples? The data I want to resample is in 32 bit IeeeFloat format.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do this and couldn't find a built in way to do it, so I did just what Mark is talking about, converting the raw data manually. Below is code to downsample IeeeFloat (32 bit float samples), 48000 samples/second, 2 channels to 16 bit short, 16000 samples/second, 1 channel.

I hardcoded some things because my formats were known and fixed, but the same principles apply.

```cs
private DownsampleFile()
        {
            var file = {your file}

            using (var reader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(file.FullName))
            using (var writer = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter({your output file}, MyWaveFormat))
            {
                float[] floats;

                //a variable to flag the mod 3-ness of the current sample
                //we're mapping 48000 --> 16000, so we need to average 3 source
                //samples to make 1 output sample
                var arity = -1;

                var runningSamples = new short[3];
                while ((floats = reader.ReadNextSampleFrame()) != null)
                {
                    //simple average to collapse 2 channels into 1
                    float mono = (float)((double)floaters[0] + (double)floaters[1]) / 2;

                    //convert (-1, 1) range int to short
                    short sixteenbit = (short)(mono * 32767);

                    //the input is 48000Hz and the output is 16000Hz, so we need 1/3rd of the data points
                    //so save up 3 running samples and then mix and write to the file
                    arity = (arity + 1) % 3;

                    runningSamples[arity] = sixteenbit;

                    //on the third of 3 running samples
                    if (arity == 2)
                    {
                        //simple average of the 3 and put in the 0th position
                        runningSamples[0] = (short)(((int)runningSamples[0] + (int)runningSamples[1] + (int)runningSamples[2]) / 3);

                        //write the one 16 bit short to the output
                        writer.WriteData(runningSamples, 0, 1);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```