# Converting WasapiLoopbackCapture buffer to PCM

Tags: c#, naudio, dsharp+

I am currently writing a Discord bot using D#+, that is supposed to send all audio that's coming through an output sound device to a voice channel.

Using NAudio, I can successfully capture the audio from a device, and my current code looks somewhat like this:

```cs
Capture.StartRecording(); // 'Capture' is a WasapiLoopbackCapture object
Capture.DataAvailable += async (s, a) =>
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(a.Buffer); // 'stream' is the transmit stream for the Discord connection
};
```

Unfortunaltey however, D#+ is very specific about requiring 16bit stereo PCM at a sample rate of 48000 Hz, which is not quite the same as the IEEE Floating Point format that the Wasapi Capture Buffer produces, as I found out through some reading. So I know by now that I have to convert the buffer to said PCM format before being able to write it into the Transmit Stream.

After some research, I found some articles like [this one](https://markheath.net/post/input-driven-resampling-with-naudio-using-acm) and questions on here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547536/convert-audio-data-in-ieeefloat-buffer-to-pcm-in-buffer), that all generally seem to go into the right direction of what I want to achieve, but not *quite*, or at least I am too unskilled with audio processing to apply it properly and make it work.

So my question is, essentially, how can I constantly convert the data that I get from the WasapiLoopbackCapture buffer into a new buffer with said PCM format? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `var sp = Capture.ToBufferedWaveProvider().ToSampleProvider(); sp.Read(buffer, ...)`? Once you have an `ISampleProvider` you could also resample it like [this](https://github.com/bert2/DtmfDetection/blob/51f96b99eb106518f34b602e21f1271445f58816/src/DtmfDetection.NAudio/SampleProviderExt.cs).

Comment: BTW [this lib/tool](https://github.com/bert2/DtmfDetection/blob/master/example/dtmf-detector/Program.cs) does turn a `WasapiLoopbackCapture` into a PCM stream. Maybe you'll find a solution there.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride The methods you mention seem to come specifically from this DTMF tone detection library, I have to say I also don't quite understand how exactly it converts the WasapiLoopbackCapture to PCM, looks like it just changes the sample rate and optionally reduces the audio to a single channel. Wouldn't that still be in the IEEE format though? (sorry, this feels like a total noob question, I'm very new with audio processing in C#!)

Comment: No worries, not a stupid question at all. Actually my fault, because I pointed you in the wrong direction.

Comment: I assume you have seen [this](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/174) already? I'm suprised by how complicated this is to achieve with NAudio...

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride You know what, I had seen that, but couldn't really make sense of it as the code seemed to be all over the place so I kind of dismissed it after I saw that the `WdlResampler` class that apparently was the solution to this isn't accessible in the current version of NAudio. But I went back to their previous steps and  with that actually wrote a working method that does the conversion! Many thanks for pointing me into this direction again, I will post the code in a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @GoodNightNerdPride for pointing me to [this issue](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/174) on the NAudio GitHub Page. With the code snippets posted in there, I was able to write this method, which can convert the buffer from an WasapiLoopbackCapture object into 16bit PCM format.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Converts an IEEE Floating Point audio buffer into a 16bit PCM compatible buffer.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputBuffer">The buffer in IEEE Floating Point format.</param>
/// <param name="length">The number of bytes in the buffer.</param>
/// <param name="format">The WaveFormat of the buffer.</param>
/// <returns>A byte array that represents the given buffer converted into PCM format.</returns>
public byte[] ToPCM16(byte[] inputBuffer, int length, WaveFormat format)
{
    if (length == 0)
        return new byte[0]; // No bytes recorded, return empty array.

    // Create a WaveStream from the input buffer.
    using var memStream = new MemoryStream(inputBuffer, 0, length);
    using var inputStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(memStream, format);

    // Convert the input stream to a WaveProvider in 16bit PCM format with sample rate of 48000 Hz.
    var convertedPCM = new SampleToWaveProvider16(
        new WdlResamplingSampleProvider(
            new WaveToSampleProvider(inputStream),
            48000)
        );

    byte[] convertedBuffer = new byte[length];

    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    int read;
            
    // Read the converted WaveProvider into a buffer and turn it into a Stream.
    while ((read = convertedPCM.Read(convertedBuffer, 0, length)) > 0)
        stream.Write(convertedBuffer, 0, read);

    // Return the converted Stream as a byte array.
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

With this, streaming the audio captured via `WasapiLoopbackCapture` to Discord using D#+ is as simple as this:

```cs
var stream = connection.GetTransmitSink();

Capture.StartRecording();
Capture.DataAvailable += async (s, a) =>
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(ToPCM16(a.Buffer, a.BytesRecorded, Capture.WaveFormat));
};
```